# Inconsistent DOM structure of the loaded HTML page in webview

Tags: android, dom, xpath, webview, rangy

I am making **Highlighter** for Android in WebView.

For the highlighting purpose, in one example i am using **JQuery** and **Rangy**, in another pure **Javascript** and **XPath**. I am trying the same **Highlight** in **Desktop Browsers** also.

Please refer to the previous questions which i posted for the problems which i am facing during **Highlighting**...

-->> [Problem when using **XPath**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999970/document-evaluate-does-not-returns-proper-textnodes-xpath)

-->> [Problem when using **Rangy**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009552/rangy-deserialize-not-working-on-webview-android)  (Not answered yet!)

So... from the responses to these question, i came to the conclusion that

**the DOM structure of the loaded HTML in WebView is inconsistent and different than that of the same HTML page loaded in Desktop Browser mostly with reference to "TextNodes"**..

To support this conclusion, i have created a jsFiddle (link in the question).
But, i also think that WebView may not be changing the DOM structure but it surely returns incorrect **TextNodes** inside a div...

Now the question is, is there any way to stop this change in DOM structure of the HTML in WebView?
**Any insight guys?**

Comment: I know this question is old, but I came across the same problem recently and found that the inconsistent DOM structure was actually due to some javascript in a library that was used to handle WebView text selection. Without that selection library, the DOM structure remains consistent. So probably, somewhere in the code, something is modifying the HTML.